# How to implement the Plaid identity verification product in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, plaid

How to implement the Plaid identity verification product in Laravel? I am confused about implementing this product. I've tried the `github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php` package and successfully implemented the Investments product in Laravel. I want to implement an identity verification product in Laravel using a template from Plaid. Can someone explain how to implement the Plaid identity verification product in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved using the Plaid SDK PHP and jQuery. Below is an example of the codes.

**plaid.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.isVerificationLinkClicked = false;
    window.isInitialVerificationChecked = false;
    if($('.identity-verification').length) {
        getVerificationLink();
        checkVerificationStatus();
    }

    $('.identity-verification').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).data('verificationLink'), '_blank');
        window.isVerificationLinkClicked = true;
        checkVerificationStatus();
    })

    function createLinkToken() {
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
            },
            url: "/createLinkToken",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                console.log('Link Token: ' + data.link_token);
                linkPlaidAccount(data.link_token);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log('Error creating link token.');
                const errMsg = JSON.parse(err);
                alert(err.error_message);
                console.error("Error creating link token: ", err);
            }
        });
    }

    function linkPlaidAccount(linkToken) {
        var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
            token: linkToken,
            onSuccess: function (public_token, metadata) {
                var body = {
                    public_token: public_token,
                    accounts: metadata.accounts,
                    institution: metadata.institution,
                    link_session_id: metadata.link_session_id,
                    link_token: linkToken
                };
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
                    },
                    url: "/storePlaidAccount",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: body,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        getInvestmentHoldings(data.item_id);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log('Error linking Plaid account.');
                        const errMsg = JSON.parse(err);
                        console.error("Error linking Plaid account: ", err);
                    }
                });
            },
            onExit: function (err, metadata) {
                console.log("linkBankAccount error=", err, metadata);
                const errMsg = JSON.parse(err);
                        console.error("Error linking Plaid account: ", err);

                linkHandler.destroy();
                if (metadata.link_session_id == null && metadata.status == "requires_credentials") {
                    createLinkToken();
                }
            }
        });
        linkHandler.open();
    }

    function checkVerificationStatus() {
        if(window.isInitialVerificationChecked == true && isVerificationLinkClicked == false) {
            return true;
        }
        window.isInitialVerificationChecked = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/check-identity-verification-status',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                _token: $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == false) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        checkVerificationStatus();
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    updateContactInformation();
                    $('.identity-verification').fadeOut(500, function () {
                        $('.identity-verification').remove();
                        window.isVerificationLinkClicked = false;
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function getVerificationLink() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/generate-verification-link',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                _token: $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.identity-verification').data('verification-link', response.verificationLink);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function updateContactInformation() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/update-contact-information',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                _token: $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"),
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.status == true) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Information updated!',
                        text: "We have updated your contact information. ",
                        icon: 'info',
                        showCancelButton: false,
                        confirmButtonText: 'View',
                        allowEscapeKey: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                    }).then(function(result) {
                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                            window.location.href = '/account-settings/personal-info';
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**PlaidController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Interfaces\PlaidRepositoryInterface;
use App\Models\PlaidAccount;
use App\Models\PlaidIdentityVerification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Plaid;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\Entities\User;
use TomorrowIdeas\Plaid\PlaidRequestException;

class PlaidController extends Controller
{
    private PlaidRepositoryInterface $plaidRepository;

    public function __construct(PlaidRepositoryInterface $plaidRepository)
    {
        $this->plaidRepository = $plaidRepository;
    }

    public function createLinkToken()
    {
        $user_id = 1;
        $plaidUser = new User($user_id);
        $plaid = new Plaid(env('PLAID_CLIENT_ID'), env('PLAID_SECRET'), env('PLAID_ENV'));
        $response = $plaid->tokens->create('Plaid Test', 'en', ['US'], $plaidUser, ['investments'], env('PLAID_WEBHOOK'));

        return response()->json([
            'result' => 'success',
            'data' => json_encode($response)
        ], 200);
    }

    public function storePlaidAccount(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'public_token' => ['required', 'string']
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['result' => 'error', 'message' => $validator->errors()], 201);
        }

        $user_id = 1;
        Log::info('-----------------------------------------');
        Log::info('Plaid public_token : ' . $request->public_token . ', link_token: ' . $request->link_token);
        $plaid = new Plaid(env('PLAID_CLIENT_ID'), env('PLAID_SECRET'), env('PLAID_ENV'));
        $obj = $plaid->items->exchangeToken($request->public_token);
        Log::info('Plaid exchange token : ' . json_encode($obj));

        try {
            \DB::transaction(function () use($request, $obj, $user_id) {
                foreach($request->accounts as $account) {
                    $query = PlaidAccount::where('account_id', isset($account['id']) ? $account['id'] : $account['account_id']);
                    if ($query->count() > 0) {
                        Log::info('[Update Plaid Account]: ' . json_encode($account));
                        $new_account = $query->first();
                        $new_account->plaid_item_id = $obj->item_id;
                        $new_account->plaid_access_token = $obj->access_token;
                        $new_account->plaid_public_token = $request->public_token;
                        $new_account->link_session_id = $request->link_session_id;
                        $new_account->link_token = $request->link_token;
                        $new_account->institution_id = $request->institution['institution_id'];
                        $new_account->institution_name = $request->institution['name'];
                        $new_account->account_id = isset($account['id']) ? $account['id'] : $account['account_id'];
                        $new_account->account_name = isset($account['name']) ? $account['name'] : $account['account_name'];
                        $new_account->account_mask = isset($account['account_number']) ? $account['account_number'] : $account['mask'];
                        $new_account->account_mask = null;
                        $new_account->account_type = isset($account['type']) ? $account['type'] : $account['account_type'];
                        $new_account->account_subtype = isset($account['subtype']) ? $account['subtype'] : $account['account_sub_type'];
                        $new_account->user_id = $user_id;
                        $new_account->save();
                    } else {
                        Log::info('[New Plaid Account]: ' . json_encode($account));
                        $new_account = ([
                            'plaid_item_id' => $obj->item_id,
                            'plaid_access_token' => $obj->access_token,
                            'plaid_public_token' => $request->public_token,
                            'link_session_id' => $request->link_session_id,
                            'link_token' => $request->link_token,
                            'institution_id'    => $request->institution['institution_id'],
                            'institution_name' => $request->institution['name'],
                            'account_id' => isset($account['id']) ? $account['id'] : $account['account_id'],
                            'account_name' => isset($account['name']) ? $account['name'] : $account['account_name'],
                            'account_mask' => isset($account['account_number']) ? $account['account_number'] : $account['mask'],
                            'account_mask' => null,
                            'account_type' => isset($account['type']) ? $account['type'] : $account['account_type'],
                            'account_subtype' => isset($account['subtype']) ? $account['subtype'] : $account['account_sub_type'],
                            'user_id' => $user_id
                        ]);
                        PlaidAccount::create($new_account);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('An error occurred linking a Plaid account: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'An error occurred attempting to link a Plaid account.'
            ], 200);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully linked plaid account.',
            'item_id' => $obj->item_id,
        ], 200);
    }

    public function checkIdentityVerificationStatus() {
        $status = $this->plaidRepository->checkVerificationStatus();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status
        ]);
    }

    public function generateVerificationLink()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'verificationLink' => $this->plaidRepository->generateVerificationLink(),
        ]);
    }

    public function updateContactInformation() {
        $status = $this->plaidRepository->updateContactInformation();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**PlaidRepositoryInterface.php**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Interfaces;


interface PlaidRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * To generate the Verification link
     * @return String
     */
    public function generateVerificationLink();

    /**
     * To check if the user has completed the verification or not
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function checkVerificationStatus();

    /**
     * To update the verification status
     * @param String $identityVerificationId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function updateVerificationStatus($identityVerificationId);

    /**
     * To update the contact information if the information does not match with the IDV.
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function updateContactInformation();

    /**
     * To save the uploaded documents in our system
     * @param $response
     * @return void
     */
    public function saveDocumentFiles($response);

    /**
     * To restart the verification process from the starting
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function retryVerificationProcess();
}
```

**PlaidRepository.php**

```php
<?php


namespace App\Repositories;


use App\Interfaces\PlaidRepositoryInterface;
use App\Models\Country;
use App\Models\PlaidIdentityVerification;
use App\Models\State;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PlaidRepository implements PlaidRepositoryInterface
{
    private function getEnvironmentURL()
    {
        $plaidEnvironments = [
            "production" => "https://production.plaid.com/",
            "development" => "https://development.plaid.com/",
            "sandbox" => "https://sandbox.plaid.com/",
        ];

        return $plaidEnvironments[env('PLAID_ENV') ?? 'production'];
    }

    public function generateVerificationLink()
    {

        if ($this->checkVerificationStatus() == true) {
            return true;
        }

        $user = Auth::user();

        $plaidIdentityVerification = PlaidIdentityVerification::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

        if (is_null($plaidIdentityVerification) == false) {
            if ($plaidIdentityVerification->status == 'failed') {
                return $this->retryVerificationProcess();
            }
            return $plaidIdentityVerification->verification_link;
        }


        $curl = curl_init();

        $payload = [
            "client_id" => env('PLAID_CLIENT_ID'),
            "secret" => env('PLAID_SECRET'),
            "template_id" => env('PLAID_IDENTITY_VERIFICATION_TEMPLATE_ID'),
            "gave_consent" => false,
            "is_shareable" => true,
            "is_idempotent" => true,
            "user" => [
                "client_user_id" => 'user-' . $user->id,
                "email_address" => $user->email,
            ]
        ];

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->getEnvironmentURL() . 'identity_verification/create',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

        curl_close($curl);

        $plaidIdentityVerification = new PlaidIdentityVerification();
        $plaidIdentityVerification->user_id = $user->id;
        $plaidIdentityVerification->identity_verification_id = $response['id'];
        $plaidIdentityVerification->verification_link = $response['shareable_url'];
        $plaidIdentityVerification->save();

        return $response['shareable_url'];
    }

    public function checkVerificationStatus()
    {
        $plaidIdentityVerification = PlaidIdentityVerification::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

        if (is_null($plaidIdentityVerification) == false) {
            $this->updateVerificationStatus($plaidIdentityVerification->identity_verification_id);
            if ($plaidIdentityVerification->status == 'success') {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function updateVerificationStatus($identityVerificationId)
    {
        $payload = [
            "client_id" => env('PLAID_CLIENT_ID'),
            "secret" => env('PLAID_SECRET'),
            "identity_verification_id" => $identityVerificationId,
        ];

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->getEnvironmentURL() . 'identity_verification/get',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

        if ($response['documentary_verification'] !== null) {
            $plaidIdentityVerification = PlaidIdentityVerification::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $plaidIdentityVerification->status = $response['documentary_verification']['status'];

            if (isset($response['documentary_verification']['status']) && $response['documentary_verification']['status'] == 'success') {
                Auth::user()->removeRole('User');
                Auth::user()->assignRole('Host');
            }

            $plaidIdentityVerification->response = json_encode($response);

            $lastKey = array_keys($response['documentary_verification']['documents']);
            $lastKey = array_values(array_reverse($lastKey))[0];

            $plaidIdentityVerification->document_type = ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $response['documentary_verification']['documents'][$lastKey]['extracted_data']['category']));
            $plaidIdentityVerification->save();
        }

        curl_close($curl);
    }

    /**
     * To update the contact information if the information does not match with the IDV.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function updateContactInformation()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userProfile = $user->profile;

        $plaidIdentificationVerification = $user->plaidIdentityVerification;
        $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse = json_decode($plaidIdentificationVerification->response, true);

        $isInformationUpdated = false;
        if (!empty($plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse)) {
            if (is_null($userProfile->country) || $userProfile->country->iso2 != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['country']) {
                $country = Country::where('iso2', $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['country'])->first();
                $user->profile->update([
                    'country_id' => $country->id,
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            }

            if (is_null($userProfile->state) || $userProfile->state->iso2 != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['region']) {
                $state = State::where('iso2', $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['region'])->first();
                $user->profile->update([
                    'state_id' => $state->id,
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($userProfile->city != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['city']) {
                $user->profile->update([
                    'city' => $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['city'],
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($userProfile->address1 != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['street']) {
                $user->profile->update([
                    'address1' => $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['street'],
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($userProfile->address2 != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['street2']) {
                $user->profile->update([
                    'address2' => $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['street2'],
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($userProfile->zip_code != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['postal_code']) {
                $user->profile->update([
                    'zip_code' => $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['address']['postal_code'],
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($userProfile->dob != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['date_of_birth']) {
                $user->profile->update([
                    'dob' => $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['date_of_birth'],
                ]);
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($user->first_name != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['name']['given_name']) {
                $user->first_name = $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['name']['given_name'];
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($user->last_name != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['name']['family_name']) {
                $user->last_name = $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['name']['family_name'];
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            if ($user->phone != $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['phone_number']) {
                $user->phone = $plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse['user']['phone_number'];
                $user->phone_verified_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $isInformationUpdated = true;
            };

            $user->save();

        }

        $this->saveDocumentFiles($plaidIdentificationVerificationResponse);

        return $isInformationUpdated;
    }

    public function saveDocumentFiles($response)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->path('');

        if (file_exists($path . '/idv/') == false) {
            mkdir($path . '/idv/', 0755, true);
        }

        if (file_exists($path . '/idv/' . $user->id) == false) {
            mkdir($path . '/idv/' . $user->id, 0775, true);
        }


        if (isset($response['documentary_verification']['documents']) && !empty($response['documentary_verification']['documents'])) {
            $lastKey = array_keys($response['documentary_verification']['documents']);
            $lastKey = array_values(array_reverse($lastKey))[0];

            if (file_exists($path . '/idv/' . $user->id . '/photo.jpg') == false) {
                Storage::disk('public')->put('/idv/' . $user->id . '/photo.jpg', file_get_contents($response['documentary_verification']['documents'][$lastKey]['images']['face']));
            }
            if (file_exists($path . '/idv/' . $user->id . '/front_photo.jpg') == false) {
                Storage::disk('public')->put('/idv/' . $user->id . '/front_photo.jpg', file_get_contents($response['documentary_verification']['documents'][$lastKey]['images']['original_front']));
            }
            if (file_exists($path . '/idv/' . $user->id . '/back_photo.jpg') == false) {
                Storage::disk('public')->put('/idv/' . $user->id . '/back_photo.jpg', file_get_contents($response['documentary_verification']['documents'][$lastKey]['images']['original_back']));
            }
        }
    }

    public function retryVerificationProcess()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $curl = curl_init();

        $payload = [
            "client_id" => env('PLAID_CLIENT_ID'),
            "secret" => env('PLAID_SECRET'),
            "template_id" => env('PLAID_IDENTITY_VERIFICATION_TEMPLATE_ID'),
            "strategy" => "reset",
            "client_user_id" => 'user-' . $user->id,
        ];

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->getEnvironmentURL() . 'identity_verification/retry',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

        curl_close($curl);

        $user->plaidIdentityVerification()->update([
            'identity_verification_id' => $response['id'],
            'verification_link' => $response['shareable_url'],
        ]);

        return $response['shareable_url'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP library for Plaid is a third party, unofficial client library, and as indicated in its [README](https://github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php/blob/master/README.md), it does not have support for Identity Verification. You have several options for using Plaid Identity Verification with PHP:

1. Do not use a Plaid client library and instead make direct POST calls to the Plaid API using the HTTP library of your choice.
2. Submit a PR to the [PHP client library](https://github.com/TomorrowIdeas/plaid-sdk-php) to add support for the Identity Verification endpoints you will need to use in your integration.
3. Generate your own PHP client library using Plaid's [OpenAPI specification](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-openapi) and a tool such as [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/).

Comment: Can we still use Plaid's interface if we use the first option?

Comment: @HilmiHidayat I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the pop up display of the verification flow template that has been set in Plaid.

Comment: @HilmiHidayat yes, you can.